# I am not able to use any software that requires user authorization if not using gnome (21.04)

Tags: i3-wm, policykit

I am not able to use any software that requires user authorization, like ubuntu software center (snap store), softwares updates, etc, because when it's time to ask for my password to execute the task (for example for software update) the password prompt doesn't appear and so it fails.
This happen if I am NOT using default ubuntu DE gnome. I am using i3wm.
If I am using gnome the password prompt appears so I can continue.

Reading around someone suggested to install `policykit-1-gnome` but no way, it's the same. It still doesn't ask for authorization so it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I am using `i3wm`, adding

```
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
```

to its config file resolved the issue.

The problem was that the polkit agent was not started at i3wm start so adding this line to i3wm config file makes sure that it is active.

Having it active every time there is a program that need to execute a privileged processes a password dialog appears.

Comment: Worth nothing that any Polkit agent will work (not only policykit-1-gnome). You can find a list here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit#Authentication_agents
I used `lxpolkit`.